# htaccess back to index

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm currenty working on a project, which has the following linking method
If the link is
`www.foo.com/sub/foo.php?o=1000` it opens MyContacts

`www.foo.com/sub/foo.php?o=608` it opens XYZ

...
The whole site is built on this, and only the number changes.

But you can access those files directly: 
`www.foo.com/sub/file1000.php`

So my question now is, is it possible to redirect to

`www.foo.com/sub/foo.php?o=1` - (index page) if the link is anything other than `www.foo.com/sub/foo.php`

I guess this can or could be done within .htaccess, but I don't have any knowlege in .htaccess programming.

Ty, Sebastjan

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with .htaccess, but generally I would recommend removing any content you do not want directly accessed from the documentroot. PHP can still access files that sit below your public directory.

If you use .htaccess, be sure to set specific rules, otherwise all image and css requests will be redirected back to the index

Otherwise, you can also put a line into your foo.php:

```
define('ISINCLUDED', 'YES');
```

and in each foo10000.php:

```
if(!defined('ISINCLUDED')) return;
```